# set enable_seqscan = off, through jdbc | Postgres

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I have two queries, insert and update. I did a benchmark through postgres console with a large dataset and found that postgres was not picking up the index. To solve this - I disabled seqscan for those two queries and got a huge performance boost; Postgres was able to pick up the indexes for scanning through the table.

Problem:
I am doing the same thing through jdbc

```
statement.executeUpdate("set enable_seqscan = off");
statement.executeUpdate("My_Insert_Query");
statement.executeUpdate("My_Update_Query");
statement.executeUpdate("set enable_seqscan = on");
```

But seems like postgres is not turning seq_scan off for and the queries are taking way too long to execute.

Master Table

```
Master_Id   auto-generated
child_unique     integer


Child Table
child_unique integer
Master_id integer

Insert into Master (child_unique) from Child as i WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * from Master where Master.child_unique = i.child_unique);

Update Child set Master_id = Master.Master_id from Master where Master.child_unique = Child.child_unique;
```

For every unique row in Child which is not present in Master-  I insert that into my Master table and get the auto generated Master_ID and insert it back into the Child table.

Both tables have index on child_unique.

Index is picked up on the Master table where as it is not in the case of Child table.
How did I find out? Using Postgres's pg_stat_all_indexes table.

Comment: Some parameters can only be changed by superusers (I don't know which ones) so if your app uses a different user then you on the console that might be the problem. Also it is advised to not switch sequential scan off but instead tweak the planner cost constants for your server: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-CONSTANTS. For a quick start if your database fits (almost) completely into memory make random_page_cost equal to seq_page_cost. Also make sure your data has been properly analyzed.

Comment: Why don't you try to solve the real problem? Why is it that PostgreSQL thinks it's not a good idea to use the index? Could you show us the result from EXPLAIN and/or EXPLAIN ANALYZE?

Comment: Did you verify that seqscan was indeed turned off? Did you check the execution plan after turning it off?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I agree with Frank above - fix the real problem.

However, if you really want to disable seq-scans you've failed to provide any information to help you do so.

Are these statements all executed on the same connection? (turn your logging on/up in PostgreSQL's config file to find out)

Are there any other jdbc-generated bits being sent to the server? (logging again)

What does a "show enable_seqscan" return after the first statement?

Comment: Note: Child is dynamically created inside the application and within the same transaction the above SQL queries are made. I found out that if I create the Child table in a different transaction and commit it, I do not have this issue anymore.

Now the problem is, why is it not picking up the index within the same transaction?

Comment: Looks like an issue with ANALYZE: auto_vacuum (also responsible for auto ananlyze) kicks in when new records are created. But only after the commit, using it's own database connection. Use ANALYZE Child; after the inserts, using your current connection, and see if there is any difference in the queryplan.